# d3 enter/append/exit/remove sequence only appending

Tags: javascript, d3.js

A set of rectangles is drawn initially with the following enter/append/exit/remove sequence, no problem. When I pass different data (meant to replace the existing data entirely) the new rectangles are drawn on top of the existing rectangles.

I am selecting "lgnds" instead of rect, because I have drawn other rectangles that I don't wish to disturb.

`var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")`

```
elements = svg
    .selectAll("lgnds")
    .data(data, function(d){return d;});

elements
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", rectHeight)
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", function (d,i){return ((i*rectHeight)+(gap*(i+1)));})
    .style("fill", function(d){ return d.color;});

elements
    .exit()
    .remove();
```

Comment: What is `lgnds`? Is that a class? The way you have it now, it looks like a tag.

Comment: I answered my own question. The problem was with the selection I was using. I needed to create a class within the rect element: e.g. .attr("class", "rect.lgnds")